# I am getting location too late when the user turns on the location when the app is open. here's my GPSTracking code

Tags: android, android-gps

I am new to Android, Creating a simple application based on the location. 
    When the user opens the app without turning on the location then it will take to the settings directly and from there if they turn on then I am 
    getting the lat and lang values too late.

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

    public class GPSTracking extends Service implements LocationListener
    {

        private final Context mContext;

        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
        private boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location mLocation;
        private double lat;
        private double lng;

        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;

        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 1;

        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracking(Context context) 
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }


        public Location getLocation() 
        {
            try 
            {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                isGPSEnabled = 

             locationManager.isProviderEnabled(lo
             cationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                isNetworkEnabled = 


                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locat
                ionManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    //no network or gps
                }
                else
                {
                    setCanGetLocation(true);

                    if (isNetworkEnabled) 
                    {
                        if(locationManager!=null)
                        {
                            mLocation = 
                            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
                            (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if(mLocation!=null)
                            {
                                setLat(mLocation.getLatitude());
                                setLng(mLocation.getLongitude());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (isGPSEnabled)
                    {
                        if (mLocation == null) 
                        {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATE,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                            if (locationManager != null) 
                            {
                                        mLocation = locationManager

                                       .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager
                                       .GPS_PROVIDER);
                                        if (mLocation != null) 
                                        {
                                            setLat(mLocation.getLatitude());
                                            setLng(mLocation.getLongitude());
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    //Exception 

            }

            return mLocation;
        }

        public void showAlertDialog()
        {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new 
                AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

                alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want go to 
                settings menu?");

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        Intent intent = new 
                        Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle 
      extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please turn on the location", 
             // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(double lng) {
            this.lng = lng; //this is the lat
        }

        public boolean isCanGetLocation() {
            return canGetLocation;
        }

        public void setCanGetLocation(boolean canGetLocation)
        {
            this.canGetLocation = canGetLocation; //this is canGetLocation which will do the following thing.
        }



    }`*
```

Comment: Unfortunately you have chosen bad example code. That approach is often known as "GPSTracker" and there are a few things wrong with it such as it `extends Service` but often isn't actually used as a Service and it requests location updates, but doesn't handle them in `onLocationChanged()`. It may work well enough though. Somebody actually wrote [a detailed blog post about the problems in that code](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, the blog's web-page is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try google api client for getting user location try this

**it will turn on location without navigating in setting like other google apps**

```
public class ActivitySignUp extends BaseActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

private Location mylocation;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 0x1;
    private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0x2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_activity);

        setUpGClient();
    }

 //set user api client for access location
    private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mylocation = location;
        if (mylocation != null) {
            Double latitude = mylocation.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = mylocation.getLongitude();

            if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                Log.e("Lat Long", "Lat " + latitude + " && Long " + longitude);
               //here is your lat long
                if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    googleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            }
            //Or Do whatever you want with your location
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        checkPermissions();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Do whatever you need
        //You can display a message here
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //You can display a message here
    }

    private void getMyLocation() {
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivitySignUp.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
                    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                            .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, ActivitySignUp.this);
                    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                            LocationServices.SettingsApi
                                    .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                            final Status status = result.getStatus();
                            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                    // All location settings are satisfied.
                                    // You can initialize location requests here.
                                    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat
                                            .checkSelfPermission(ActivitySignUp.this,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                    if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                                .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                    // But could be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                                    try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                        // Ask to turn on GPS automatically
                                        status.startResolutionForResult(ActivitySignUp.this,
                                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                        // Ignore the error.
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        getMyLocation();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivitySignUp.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        } else {
            getMyLocation();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivitySignUp.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getMyLocation();
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it depends on phone , wifi being on or off , accuracy

Also there are three types of location :

```
GPS_PROVIDER
NETWORK_PROVIDER
PASSIVE_PROVIDER
```

So, as per my experience I came to know that if you use :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, new     MyLocationListener());
```

you will get precision upto 14+ decimal places.

But if you use fusion of them like this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, my_google_listener);
```

you will get precision upto 6 to 7 decimal places. try it !!! reference

But note few things here that, GPS Provider takes time to fetch location while Google Location is much faster as it gets data from API call to its google server database.

GPS works offline while google provider gets the location via mobile or wifi data.

Comment: Thank you. Now the app is working fine when I started using mGoogleApiClient